# nginx regex engine on URL rewrite doesn't support squiggly brackets?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

My nginx config seems to fail on the syntax check if I try to use the squiggly brackets, even though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14126920/3788043) implies that nginx uses PECR, and [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/HK7qXc/1/) shows that the squiggly brackets work under PECR (although it does say PECR PHP in brackets...).

So, if I put this under my server > location block:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([0-9]{4})$ /page.php;
}
```

I get the following error from nginx's syntax checker:

> nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:37
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

And if I only get rid of the squiggly part, and leave it with this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([0-9])$ /page.php;
}
```

Then everything is okay:

> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

So, what exactly is the fault here, and how can get my URL-rewriter to accept specifically 4 digits in the URL rewrite rule?

Comment: Very nice find, thank you! Why not submit that as an answer, so I can accept the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for `rewrite`:

> If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole
>   expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

The `}` and `;` characters have a special meaning in the Nginx configuration file, so there use within a regular expression needs to be protected by enclosing the expression within quotes.

Same applies to regular expressions appearing in `location`, `if` and `map` directives (and any others I may have forgotten).

For example:

```
rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}$" /page.php last;
```